# Discrepancy with division calculation in Python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a Python 3 class method for rescaling values that looks like this:

```
class A(object):
    """docstring for A"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()

    def rescale(self, old_min, old_max, new_min, new_max, value):
         """rescales a value given a current old_min and 
         old_max to the desired new_min and new_max"""
         scale = (old_max - old_min) / (new_max - new_min)
         rescaled_value = new_min + ((value - old_min) / (scale))
         return rescaled_value
```

Using Python 3, this method works like this:

```
>>> import A
>>> x = A()
>>> x.rescale(1,10,1,100,5)
45.0
```

In Python 2.7, this code does not work:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> x = A()
>>> x.rescale(1,10,1,100,5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "bunsen.py", line 35, in rescale
rescaled_value = new_min + ((value - old_min) / (scale))
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

If I manually do this math in Python 2.7 I get the correct answer:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> scale = (10 - 1) / (100 - 1)
>>> rescaled_value = 1 + ((5 - 1) / (scale))
>>> rescaled_value
45.0
```

Can anyone point out why this method does not work in Python 2.7?

Comment: I doubt you executed the last code manually in 2.7. Integer division in 2.7 will yield an integer, not float, and `9/99` will result in `0`. Have a look at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/

Comment: @FelixKling See my edit. I originally forgot `from __future__ import division`

Comment: @dr.bunsen: Please note that, yes, you will get the error with the code you show. But the answers point out that you need to have the `from __future__ import division` **in the file that defines** `A.rescale()`. I do not believe you have that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set `from __future__ import division` in the file that contains the divisions, i.e. in the file with `A`.

Comment: I have from `__future__ import division` in the file and I do not believe that this is the problem.

Comment: Well, I've said exactly that.

Comment: @wRAR - this is most certainly the correct answer. Failing to have his import in the file containing the class defintion for A would yield the problem you are reporting

Comment: For some reason the OP deleted his comment stating that my suggestion fiexed his problem.

Comment: I've tested the code as given, and it works under 2.7 as well as Python 3. Removing the `__future__` makes it fail as described in the question. I believe you are correct. This is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

For python 2.7 you can either:

```
    x.rescale(1.0, 10.0, 1.0, 100.0, 5.0)
```

Or you could explicitly cast to float in division inside method.

```
    scale = float((old_max - old_min)) / (new_max - new_min)
```

Or another way is to import `from __future__ import division`.

This is because in python 2.x integer divided by integer will result in an integer, in your case 0.

**EDIT** after your comment:

Make sure you do the

```
    from __future__ import division
```

**IN** module A, as there is where the computations are done not like you did there.

Answer (score 1):

Using this code in 2.7:

```
from __future__ import division

class A(object):
    """docstring for A"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()

    def rescale(self, old_min, old_max, new_min, new_max, value):
         """rescales a value given a current old_min and 
         old_max to the desired new_min and new_max"""
         scale = (old_max - old_min) / (new_max - new_min)
         rescaled_value = new_min + ((value - old_min) / (scale))
         return rescaled_value 

x = A()
print x.rescale(1,10,1,100,5)
```

gives me:

```
45.0
```

If I remove the `__future__` import I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print x.rescale(1,10,1,100,5)
  File "test.py", line 11, in rescale
    rescaled_value = new_min + ((value - old_min) / (scale))
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

You **must** have the `from __future__ import division` line *in the module that defines A*.  Imports **only** affect the module they are contained in.